# how to master spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbee to spark sql. I find that to write spark query programs with complicated logic can be very tricky. For example, I know that the operators in spark sql library are quite limited, so sometimes we need to implement UDF. But how do you know if some operations are feasable by library operators? How do i know if it's necessary to implement a UDF?  I found that many developpers are able to come up with elegant program of Spark. How do you master Spark? How can I improve my programming ability with Spark SQL. Should I master MYSQL first? I am a student with a software development backgroud. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Young  . If you are asking specific to spark sql then i would suggest to improve you sql. Try complex sqls, topics include : GROUP BY, ALL JOINS, WINDOWING functions etc. This tutorial is short

https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/index.php

and introduces SQL. I dont think MySql would be important as it would be vast and it has its own implementation and different logics. Important thing for you is to learn ANSI SQL. You can practise on virtuals environment online called as fiddle.
Heres one :

https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Then you need to practise on different sql problems for which Hackerrank's SQL exercises are enough.

After that you should move to Spark SQL and explore all available functions.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.1/api/sql/

Comment: when we say explore all available functions, that means we need to go through all APIs in the library?

Comment: You don't have to practice each one. But the best bet is most answers will be solved using these APIs. So you should atleast read them